# Copy values of all visible cells in one listobject to another empty listobject?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a listobject that has tons of rows but is filtered to show only a subset of these:

```
Dim loComplete as Listobject
```

I have another listobject. I want to copy visible values from a certain column in loComplete into a certain column in this listobject.

```
Dim loOnlyFiltetedValues as ListObject
```

Both the source column and target columns are called "Course code"

My best attempt so far is:

```
Dim courseCode As Variant
courseCode = loComplete.ListColumns("Course Code").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
loOnlyFiltetedValues.ListColumns("Course Code").DataBodyRange = courseCode
```

But that doesn't work. Do you know of any elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy and Paste, I think

```
courseCode = loComplete.ListColumns("Course Code").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
loOnlyFilteredValues.ListColumns("Course Code").Range.Cells(2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Tahnk you! Are the copy and paste methods as reliable as setting Range(someting).Value = Range(something else).Value?

Comment: I wouldn't call them unreliable. I think they carry more baggage than setting values and so I set values whenever possible. But in this case, setting values isn't possible. There's something about SpecialCells that prevents the Value array from being created.